# MPI tags are disabled

Tags: c, mpi

I'm writing a knapsack problem solver using MPI. The currect optimal value for a packing is sent as a tag on a message. However, the program crached with "MPI_ERR_TAG: Invalid tag." whenever executed. After some reading of the MPI documentation, it seemed that tags had to be non-negative and less than the constant MPI_TAG_UB. On inspection of MPI_TAG_UB, I found it was set to zero, thus making all tags invalid. Why could this be? Do I have to set this value myself somehow?

Attached is a short piece of code that prints "MPI_TAG_UB = 0" and aborts on my system.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

struct P {
    char choices[64];
    int next_choice;
};

typedef struct P Packing;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    int rank;
    MPI_Datatype PACKING_TYPE;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

    /*Defines a new MPI datatype tag for Packings.*/
    int field_count = 2;
    int field_lengths[2] = {64,1};
    MPI_Aint field_offsets[2];
    field_offsets[0] = 0;
    field_offsets[1] = 64;
    MPI_Datatype field_types[2] = {MPI_CHAR,MPI_INT};
    MPI_Type_struct(field_count,field_lengths,
        field_offsets,field_types,&PACKING_TYPE);
    MPI_Type_commit(&PACKING_TYPE);

    int tag = 1;
    if (rank == 0) {
        Packing pack;
        printf("MPI_TAG_UB = %d\n",MPI_TAG_UB);
        if(MPI_TAG_UB == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Tags disabled!\n");
            abort();
        }
        MPI_Send(&pack,1,PACKING_TYPE,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        puts("Process 0 sent message.");
    }

    if (rank == 1) {
        Packing pack;
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&pack,1,PACKING_TYPE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
                MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        puts("Process 1 recieved message.");
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&PACKING_TYPE);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MPI_TAG_UB` is not an actual defined value itself, but an *environmental inquiry key*. Unfortunately you need another indirection. To check it, you can use:

```
MPI_Aint* tag_ub_ptr;
MPI_Comm_get_attr(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_TAG_UB, &tag_ub_ptr, &flag);
printf("TAG_UB is %d\n", *tag_ub_ptr);
```

Furthermore it is guaranteed to be at least 32767 and also inclusive.

I would not recommend to use the tag as an actual data value. This is not what it is intended for and abusing it this way might cost you some optimizations the implementation could otherwise do. You could use PACK/UNPACK or derived data types to send the packing and optimal value.

Comment: The code snippet above won't work.
`int *ptr, flag;
MPI_Comm_get_attr(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_TAG_UB, &ptr, &flag);
int tag_ub = *ptr;`
Sadly the MPI standard is quite ambiguous about exactly what is stored in the pointed-to memory location passed to `MPI_Comm_get_attr`.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I agree that this is confusing. The specific function description is not very helpful, but it is described in the language bindings 17.2.7 B.

Comment: Yes, I read that briefly yesterday but missed line 40: "C attribute functions put and get address-valued attributes". The examples A & B in 17.13 aren't super helpful - the pointer-to-int case seems sensible and consistent with `MPI_TAG_UB` but the integer case is misleading and also erroneous on platforms where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(void*)`.